# how to extract from collection properties and insert in into new collection model in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I have `_userLocations:[CLLocation]` collection store user geoDatas,I want to loop throw the _userLocations collection and extract timestamp,latitude, and longitude properties and insert in into model collection called `savedLocations:[Location]=[]`.when I try loop using for loop I have this error _userLocations

> ' Value of type '[Location]' has no member 'timestamp''

can someone help me ?

my model

```
   class Location {

        @NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber?
        @NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber?
        @NSManaged var timestamp: NSDate?

    }

        for location in _userLocations {
            savedLocations.timestamp = location.timestamp
            savedLocations.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
            savedLocations.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        }
```

Comment: isn't your `savedLocations` a `[Location]`? You need to create a new `Location` object and insert into `savedLocations`

Comment: yes it is array of Location

Comment: can you show my how becasue I'm new to swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error `Value of type '[Location]' has no member 'timestamp'` is because your `savedLocations` is an `[Location]`. **`Array` doesn't have a `timestamp` property**.

What you need to do is create a new `Location` object and insert into your `savedLocations`

```
for location in _userLocations {
    let newLocation = Location()
    newLocation.timestamp = location.timestamp
    newLocation.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
    newLocation.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude

    savedLocations.append(newLocation)
}
```